# Shaslik android Thread error, When I run apk. How Can I solve?

Tags: android, ubuntu, android-emulator

I am working on virtual machine which operating system is **ubuntu**. I install shashlik android emulator and install apk. But I have an error when runing an apk. Can you help me ?

```
 /opt/shashlik/bin/shashlik-run splash com.viber.voip_6.8.7.8-130265_minAPI14\(x86\)\          
(nodpi\)_APKdot.com.apk 
 starting emulator
 emulator: WARNING: system partition size adjusted to match image file (750 MB > 200 MB)

emulator: ERROR: Invalid -datadir directory: /home/x/.local/share/shashlik/system
emulator: WARNING: data partition size adjusted to match image file (750 MB > 200 MB)

setting icon3 
Creating filesystem with parameters:
  Size: 69206016
  Block size: 4096
  Blocks per group: 32768
  Inodes per group: 4224
  Inode size: 256
  Journal blocks: 1024
  Label: 
  Blocks: 16896
  Block groups: 1
  Reserved block group size: 7
Created filesystem with 11/4224 inodes and 1302/16896 blocks    
Exception in thread Thread-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/threading.py", line 916, in _bootstrap_inner
   self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/threading.py", line 864, in run
   self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/opt/shashlik/bin/shashlik-run", line 119, in send_icon
   with open(icon_path, "rb") as icon:
  FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 
  '/home/x/.local/share/shashlik/splash.png'
```

Comment: It solved because I wrote wrong apk package name, when runing an app.

Comment: I was getting the same error and fixed it with `sed -i -e 's/os\.mkdirs/os.makedirs/' /opt/shashlik/bin/shashlik-run`.